# Create a virtual machine from a managed image

Tags: ruby, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-for-ruby

I have created azure VMs successfully using the [ruby sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby) but I can't find any example for creating from a managed image. I want to do something like this but with SDK:

```
az image create --name fedora-75-20180724 --resource-group myteam --source https://eastusimg.blob.core.windows.net/images/fedora-28-20180724.vhd --os-type linux
# create vm without option "--use-unmanaged-disk, --os-type, --storage-account"
az vm create -g myteam -n managed-master --image fedora28-20180724 --size Standard_DS2_V2 --nics managed-master --os-disk-size-gb 40 --public-ip-address-dns-name managed-master --os-disk-name managed-master
```

But it is not clear to me how to do it as well can't find any example for this. Examples I looked at are [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/compute-ruby-manage-vm/blob/master/example.rb) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/blob/master/management/azure_mgmt_compute/spec/2017-03-30/virtual_machines_spec.rb). Basically I have no clue how to construct the `StorageProfile` or maybe I need something more. So I would appreciate a code example for creating such a VM.

Thank you.

Update with a working (unless I forgot something) example based on @4c74356b41's answer:

```rb
ComputeModels::StorageProfile.new.tap do |store_profile|
  store_profile.image_reference = ComputeModels::ImageReference.new.tap do |ref|
    # obtain `image` by `compute_client.images.list_by_resource_group`
    # make sure they are in the same region though or you'll see 404
    ref.id = image.id
  end
  store_profile.os_disk = ComputeModels::OSDisk.new.tap do |os_disk|
    os_disk.name = "my-unique-disk-name"
    os_disk.disk_size_gb = 42 # optionally change size
    os_disk.caching = ComputeModels::CachingTypes::ReadWrite # this is a test machine
    os_disk.create_option = ComputeModels::DiskCreateOptionTypes::FromImage
    # setting `managed_disk` is optional
    os_disk.managed_disk = ComputeModels::ManagedDiskParameters.new.tap do |params|
      params.storage_account_type = StorageModels::SkuName::StandardLRS
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what is a managed image?

Comment: @4c74356b41, see the command I have in the question. Maybe term I'm using is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i'm not a ruby person, nor I was able to locate any reasonable docs, but it should be something like this:

```
store_profile.os_disk = ComputeModels::OSDisk.new.tap do |os_disk|
    os_disk.name = "sample-os-disk-#{vm_name}"
    os_disk.caching = ComputeModels::CachingTypes::None
    os_disk.create_option = ComputeModels::DiskCreateOptionTypes::FromImage
end
```

or you might need to add the [managed disk option](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/blob/master/management/azure_mgmt_compute/lib/2018-06-01/generated/azure_mgmt_compute/models/osdisk.rb#L70) and set the storage account [type](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/blob/master/management/azure_mgmt_compute/lib/2018-06-01/generated/azure_mgmt_compute/models/managed_disk_parameters.rb#L19), but i think that is redundant.

Comment: Thanks, didn't spot these options. I don't think it will be redundant to specify the options because `ComputeModels::DiskCreateOptionTypes::FromImage` is used when creating from a storage-account vhd. I'll try these out tomorrow.

Comment: fromImage means that it will use a marketplace image to create the vm

Comment: I don't want to use marketplace. See my example in question. Actually I see that `FromImage` is used for both - marketplace and vhd (e.g. `https://myteam.blob.core.windows.net/images/fedora-20170502.vhd`). I guess it will be used for "managed" image as well. Anyway, have to try these options tomorrow.

Comment: oh, sorry, forgot about that. yeah, you would then need to use this one: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/blob/master/management/azure_mgmt_compute/lib/2018-06-01/generated/azure_mgmt_compute/models/image_reference.rb#L52, so pass in only ID to image reference.

Comment: I managed to create VMs with managed disks using the managed disk options. But only for marketplace images where ImageReference is `publisher`, `sku`, etc. When I try custom image I'm getting `The Image '/subscriptions/333-3333-33333-3333-3333/resourceGroups/myteam/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/fedora-28-20180724' cannot be found.` While this is in fact the correct id of the existing image as seen in console. Any ideas?

Comment: Found out, it was in a different location than VM. Would have been better if error message told me that there is a region mismatch instead of 404. Anyway, things are working now! In short: • specify `image_reference` by `id` when creating `storage_profile` • (optionally) specify `managed_disk_parameters` when creating `OSDisk` • thank a lot for the pointers!!!

Comment: sorry, i just noticed your question. should have probably mentioned that.